# How can i update Phonegap project created cordova 1.9 to cordova 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

How can i update Phonegap project created in 1.9 to 3.1 correctly  .

I have developed a application Phonegap application with help of phonegap 1.9 jquery mobile .Which will download remote xml and parse the content and display it , and for social media sharing  of data i used share.js.

Now i would like to give support to ios7 and iphone 5 .  so need to update my current project how can i do that .

I tried updating my project but am not getting any console. And it gives me white screen. Am not able to get any console .But am using lot of console to track the application flow .

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: there are update guides, but you should follow them one by one until you reach 3.1. Maybe it's easier if you create a new 3.1 project and paste your www folder content.

Comment: most features are not working even console fails in that . j query mobile feature are also disabled

Comment: On phonegap 3.0 and up you have to install the plugins you need. Console is a plugin now.

Comment: @jcesar : i tried adding plugins then also it's not working

Comment: use the remote debuger to see where the app is crashing. And/our use this javascript: <script>
            window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
                alert("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + url);
            }
        </script>

Comment: @jcesar can you post this an answer so i will accept this. Solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are update guides, but you should follow them one by one until you reach 3.1. Maybe it's easier if you create a new 3.1 project and paste your www folder content.

BTW, on phonegap 3.0 and up you have to install the plugins you need. Console is a plugin now.

If it doesn't work use the remote debuger to see where the app is crashing, and/our use this javascript:

```
<script> 
window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) { 
    alert("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + linenumber + " for " + url); 
} 
</script>
```